# ¿Cómo poner formato de moneda en un textbox c# Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

colegas he estado pasando varias horas sin poder conseguir que un **TextBox** me muestre un formato de moneda adecuado sin que hacer redondeo y sin aumentar 0000, la verdad es un poco cansado pero les dejo aquí mu código y se les agradece el apoyo mutuo.

```
public static void Moneda(ref TextBox cajaTexto)
    {
        string n = string.Empty;
        double b = 0;
        cajaTexto.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");
        if (n.Equals(""))
            n = "";
        n = n.PadLeft(3, '0');
        if (n.Length > 3 & n.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
            n = n.Substring(1, n.Length - 1);
        b = Convert.ToDouble(n) / 100;
        cajaTexto.Text = string.Format("{0:C2}", b);
        cajaTexto.SelectionStart = cajaTexto.Text.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Podes aclarar como queres que sea el formato, y como esta siendo ahora...

Comment: Quiero que el formato de moneda sea 00,0 y no genere redondeo. Ahora esta omitiendo o redondeando los decimales y yo los quiero mantener los decimales sin redondeo.

Comment: Eso te pasa en la division supongo.. podrias poner ejemplos de los casos? y tambien, porque directamente no cortas el string?

Comment: Como cortar directamente, disculpe la ignorancia pero es la primera vez que trabajo con monedas y es muy rudo. Lo que pasa es que quiero armar una clase que sea reutilizable en los de mas formularios.

Comment: vos tenes un string.. si solo queres sacar decimales, podrias tomar tantos caracteres como necesites menos los ultimos y dejar eso directamente. por eso te pedia ejemplos.

Comment: yo tengo un valor decimal y el TextBox no me lee como tal si no que redondea prove varias manera como esta por ejemplo.
textbox1.Text =string.Format("{0:C2}", 2);
Pero igual redondea

Comment: Si porque por defecto cuando transformas un numero se redondea. Por eso pido ejemplos. El texbox no hace nada con el nunero, vos lo estas transformando haciendo todo eso.

Comment: Te explico como lo estoy manejando, yo tengo un GUI donde muestra la tabla producto (DataGridView) y otro de venta, al momento de pasar el precio es redondeado y eso es lo que quiero controlar que no se redondee y muestre el valor original (SubTotales).

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar. Los numeros no son numeros. Son cadenas. Y vos queres sacarle caracteres a las cadenas. Por favor pone ejemplos y arreglamos esos ejemplos

Comment: No me queda del todo claro lo que pretendes hacer, vos tenes un número en `decimal` y queres mostrarlo dentro de un `TextBox` sin perder presición?

Comment: Así es, pero aun no lo logro me aumenta 2 ceros es decir si es 2.50 me sale 2,5000 y eso es lo que quiero corregir como podría controlar eso?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer es lo siguiente:

```
cajaTexto.Text = b.ToString("C");
```

Un saludo